# Access downloaded image file in fileTransferUtility.BeginDownload

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How do I access the downloaded file when downloading an S3 image using [fileTransferUtility.BeginDownload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_S3_Transfer_TransferUtility_BeginDownload.htm)?

In my async callback function I have an `IAsyncResult` paramter, but it doesn't provides any access to the downloadable image file from S3.

I am using the C#/.NET AWS SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [TransferUtilityDownloadRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_S3_Transfer_TransferUtilityDownloadRequest.htm) object should have a [FilePath](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/P_Amazon_S3_Transfer_TransferUtilityDownloadRequest_FilePath.htm) property.  If your download is finishing successfully, then you should check the value of `FilePath` and access the file at that location upon receiving the callback.

Comment: LOL, I thought it was for the S3 object. However, Is there any option to get a stream of the file with an async function. I don't need to save it to disk, just manipulate it in memory and upload back?

Comment: @IdanShechter Haven't used them myself, but it sounds like you might be looking for [BeginGetObject](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_S3_AmazonS3Client_BeginGetObject.htm) and [EndGetObject](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_S3_AmazonS3Client_EndGetObject.htm).